# 502 error on deploying the default Play 2.0 java application to cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I can't get my play applications to run on cloudfoundry.com. I tried with the most simple java application generated by Play 2.0.2. When I visit mysampleplay.cloudfoundry.com, I get the nginx error: 502 Bad Gateway.

I have no reported crashes and vcm logs says my service is running. Any suggestions?

These are the instructions I typed:

```
C:\javadev\prj\play>play new sample
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.0.2, http://www.playframework.org

The new application will be created in C:\javadev\prj\play\sample

    What is the application name?
> sample

Which template do you want to use for this new application?

  1 - Create a simple Scala application
  2 - Create a simple Java application
  3 - Create an empty project

> 2

OK, application sample is created.

Have fun!


C:\javadev\prj\play>cd sample

C:\javadev\prj\play\sample>ls
README   app      conf     project  public

C:\javadev\prj\play\sample>play clean dist
[info] Loading project definition from C:\javadev\prj\play\sample\project
[info] Set current project to sample (in build file:/C:/javadev/prj/play/sample/
)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 11-jul-2012 19:05:55
[info] Updating {file:/C:/javadev/prj/play/sample/}sample...
[info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Fin

[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\javadev\prj\play\sample\target\scala-2.9.1\classes...
[info] Packaging C:\javadev\prj\play\sample\target\scala-2.9.1\sample_2.9.1-1.0-
SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.

Your application is ready in C:\javadev\prj\play\sample\dist\sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT
.zip

[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 11-jul-2012 19:06:00

C:\javadev\prj\play\sample>vmc push --path=dist\sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
Application Name: mysampleplay
    Detected a Play Framework Application, is this correct? [Yn]: y
Application Deployed URL [mysampleplay.cloudfoundry.com]:
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [256M]:
How many instances? [1]: 1
Bind existing services to 'mysampleplay'? [yN]: n
Create services to bind to 'mysampleplay'? [yN]: n
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: y
Manifest written to manifest.yml.
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (66K): OK
Push Status: OK

Staging Application 'mysampleplay': OK

Starting Application 'mysampleplay': OK


C:\javadev\prj\play\sample>vmc logs mysampleplay
====> /logs/stdout.log <====

No database found in Play configuration.  Skipping auto-reconfiguration.
Play server process ID is 31827
[←[33mwarn←[0m] play - Plugin [org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.play.JPAPlugin]
is disabled
[←[37minfo←[0m] play - Application started (Prod)
[←[37minfo←[0m] play - Listening for HTTP on port 24712...
```

Comment: Hi Willem, how many times have you tried to deploy the application? I followed the exact same steps (albeit on MacOS) and the application deployed fine.. http://dhigham-play.cloudfoundry.com/

Comment: Only once. I had the same difficulties with another application I developed and I tried that one several times . Because it didn't work, I thought let's start with a simple application first. I'm using Windows 8 (release preview)

Comment: Can you send the archive you deployed using vmc to support@cloudfoundry.com and we will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

We found the cause together with cloudfoundry support. My classes were compiled with Java 7u5, so you must explicitely specify the runtime

vmc push --path=dist/application.zip --runtime java7